# Database connection moqui issue

Tags: moqui

I call  , it return error:
Cannot get connection, transaction not in operable status (Marked Rollback-Only (1))

- Some other warnings:
  Tried to commit transaction but marked rollback only, doing rollback instead; rollback-only was set here
  Rollback only not set on current transaction, status is STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION

Is there any configuration in database to resolve this issue?

Comment: More information is needed to know what is going on. It is normal for a transaction to be rolled back because of a rollback in code that did not begin the transaction. For example, a service is called and there is no transaction in place so it begins one, then that service calls another service which has an error but that service did not begin the transaction so it doesn't roll it back, it marks it for rollback only because of the error. Look earlier in the logs for the original error, and the log message Moqui generates with the location of setting the rollback only flag.